# why my function inside button didnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

so this is my highschool project,

This is the Button

```
<button onclick="btncncl(); location.href='hapus.php?id=<?= $dp["ID"]; ?>'" class="button-64" role="button"><span class="text">Delete</span></button>
```

this is the javascript (swal)

```
function btncncl() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    }
  });
}
```

the button works, but the swal function doesn't appear, and this code is inside php file

Comment: do you get any errors in the JS/browser console?

Comment: it was there but accidentally deleted it, if I'm not mistaken btncncl is undefined

Comment: Because you are not passing the parameter ID into your function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing the parameter ID into your function.

```
<button onclick="btncncl(<?= $dp["ID"]; ?>)" class="button-64" role="button">Delete</button>


function btncncl(id = null) {
    if(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "yourCancelPHPFile.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: id},
            dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response) {
                    if(response.success == true) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            toast: true,
                            icon: response.icon,
                            title: response.title,
                            position: 'top',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000,
                            timerProgressBar: true,
                        });
                        
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire({
                            toast: true,
                            icon: response.icon,
                            title: response.title,
                            position: 'top',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000,
                            timerProgressBar: true,
                        });
                    } 
                } 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution,

- I test it. you also can run and check the code.
- Note: this is sweetalert2. You need to link js of it. (external or internal)
- check the full code below.

```js
document.getElementById("deleteBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      location.href='hapus.php?id=<?= $dp["ID"]; ?>';
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="deleteBtn" class="button-64" role="button"><span class="text">Delete</span></button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<script src="btncncl.js"></script>
```

*Hope you will fix it : )*

Comment: thanks, i already put the sweetalert js (local)

Comment: whta about the location.href?

Comment: location.href returns you to specific page after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btncncl() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick=btncncl() location.href='hapus.php?id=<?= $dp["ID"]; ?>' class="button-64" role="button"><span class="text">Delete</span></button>
```

Hey... Look at this part
onclick="btncncl();

Comment: It throws console log error. Not a correct  answer.